# Recursion Exercises

Tags: java, recursion

So I'am given the following problem: 
We have bunnies standing in a line, numbered 1, 2, ... The odd bunnies (1, 3, ..) have the normal 2 ears. The even bunnies (2, 4, ..) we'll say have 3 ears, because they each have a raised foot. Recursively return the number of "ears" in the bunny line 1, 2, ... n (without loops or multiplication).

and here is my source code. I am using Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BunnyEars
{
    public static int CountEars(int i, int e)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            return e;
        }
        else if(i > 0)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                e = e + 2;
                i = i - 1;
                CountEars(i,e);
            }
            else
            {
                e = e + 3;
                i = i - 1;
                CountEars(i,e);
            }       
        }
        return e;
    }

public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int b;
    int result;

    System.out.println("Bunny Ears, even has 2 ears, odd has 3 ears");
    System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");
    b = scan.nextInt();

    result = CountEars(b,0);

    System.out.println("Number of ears are: " + result);
}
```

If I enter 5 the output is supposed to be 12 but the output is 3.
So I think the CountEars(i,e) method in

```
enter code here

if(i%2==0)
        {
            e = e + 2;
            i = i - 1;
            CountEars(i,e);
        }
        else
        {
            e = e + 3;
            i = i - 1;
            CountEars(i,e);
        }
```

is not executing. I can't seem to find my mistakes. Anyone?

Comment: Use a debugger + some `sysouts`.

Comment: You think it is not executing? Have you tried inserting System.out.println("HERE!") in the block see if it really does not execute?

Comment: You add to the method-local argument `int e`. This is unique for every method call. You either need to return the number of ears back to the calling function or (as the answer states) use an independent integer to store your amount of ears to.

Answer (score 1):

In your recursive method you're not totaling in the return values from the other bunnies in the line.  Also, you only need one argument -- which bunny is under consideration.

```
/*
 * Return the total number of ears in a line of length n
 */
public static int countEars(int n) {
   if (n < 1) {
      return 0;   // base case: no bunnies, no ears
   }
   // Below we make the "recursive leap of faith": if this
   // function works, we can get the answer for a line of n-1
   // bunnies and add the current bunny's ears to it to yield
   // the correct answer for the current value of n.
   // Note that the argument to the recursive call must
   // converge towards the base case for this to work.
   if (n % 2 == 1) {
      return 2 + countEars(n-1);
   }
   return 3 + countEars(n-1);
}
```

Invoke this with `result = countEars(5);`.

Note that I've renamed your method to follow Java conventions as well.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BunnyEars {

static int e=0;
public static int CountEars(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return e;
    } else if (i > 0) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            e = e + 2;
            //i = i - 1;
            CountEars(i-1);
        } else {
            e = e + 3;
            //i = i - 1;
            CountEars(i-1);
        }
    }
    return e;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int b;
    int result;

    System.out.println("Bunny Ears, even has 2 ears, odd has 3 ears");
    System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");
    b = scan.nextInt();

    result = CountEars(b);

    System.out.println("Number of ears are: " + result);
}
}
```

Comment: Why? Please explain what you have changed.

Comment: I am not passing e in the method, and i put it as global variable.

Comment: The problem is " e reset each recursive call, and took the value from first call 5"

Comment: Making `e` static is not good advice. What if the method is called again?

Comment: I put it just to call from main method, I wanted to fix the issue in his code.
static is not mandatory.